# Is the error message "The Microsoft Jet database engine can not find the input table or query" the result of a hardware limitation?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.2

I'm using ArcMap 10.2.1.

When I try to compute a union of two shapefiles, I get this message:

> "The Microsoft Jet database engine can not find the input table or query. Make sure it exists and its name is correctly spelled".

The table name that can't be found corresponds to the output shapefile that is given by me (name and location).

I have already performed this operation successfully with two similar files, but now this is the only thing I get.

Can this be a memory problem?

Comment: Afraid we need a bit more info, the error message alludes to names, so what are they? What are your inputs and outputs called?